# Chrome browser closes automatically when run chromedriver inside a method/function

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I was trying to run some selenium test in chrome browser in Pycharm IDE.I wrote the chrome driver inside a function & when i tried to run the code it opened up the  browser and closed automatically within a sec.But when I wrote the chrome driver outside the function it open the browser and didnot close. How do i manage to keep the browser open if I write the chromedriver code inside a method/function?

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

class Chrome:
    def Run(self):
        driverLocation="F:\\Workspace py\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
        os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = driverLocation
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverLocation)
        driver.get("https://www.google.com")


Test=Chrome()
Test.Run()
```

Comment: Since the `driver` is a local variable in the `Run` function, I bet the Python interpreter is closing the browser window automatically because the `Run` function exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import os

class Chrome:
    def Run(self):
        self.driverLocation="F:\\Workspace py\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
        os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = self.driverLocation
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverLocation)
        self.driver.get("https://www.google.com")


Test=Chrome()
Test.Run()
```